# iptables remove specific rules according to uid

Tags: linux, iptables

Say, I've add 3 rules like this:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -s google.com -m owner --uid-owner 10011 -j DROP
# iptables -A INPUT -s facebook.com -m owner --uid-owner 10011 -j DROP
# iptables -A INPUT -s microsoft.com -m owner --uid-owner 10022 -j DROP
```

Now I want to remove all the rules with uid 10011. Is there any possible command to make that? Try to find rules and remove them one by one is an idea but not good enough.

Answer (score 1):

`iptables --line-numbers -L INPUT | awk '/UID match 10011/{ print $1 }' | sort -r | while read num ; do iptables -D INPUT ${num} ; done`

Notice that `iptables -D` can delete only one rule at a time. When we delete one rule, their numbers might change, so we must delete them by decreasing numbers, hence the `sort -r`.